# WPF incrementing bound property in for loop doesn't notify UI, and blocks it

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have very weird problem with wpf and mvvm. Imagine you have one `textbox` bound to `Counter` property on view model. And button changes property on view model, which raises `PropertyChanged` event and UI is updated. Well, that is exactly what's happening if i do something like `Counter++` But, when i try to do that in for loop, to change `Counter` property 10 times on one click, it blocks UI and display just last string at the end of the loop.. Here is code:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int counter;

    public int Counter
    {
        get { return counter; }
        set { counter = value; Notify("Counter"); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Counter = 0;
    }

    public void inc()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Counter++;
        }           
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void Notify(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        var dataContext = button.DataContext as MainViewModel;
        dataContext.inc();
    }
}



<Window x:Class="WpfTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/prototyping/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTests"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel></local:MainViewModel>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="40,106,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Counter}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="287,106,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button_Click">

    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Seems like you used `Thread.Sleep` on the GUI thread which freezes the GUI

Comment: I don't use it, i just created new wpf application, simple as can be, i pasted code here so you can take a look, or try to run it on you machine and see what happens. If you change `inc()` function on view model to do just one increment, without loop, it works, every click updates UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well, that is exactly what's happening if i do something like Counter++ But, when i try to do that in for loop, to change Counter property 10 times on one click, it blocks UI and display just last string at the end of the loop.

When you are changing the Counter property, you are doing that in the UI thread. During that time the UI thread is blocked. As soon as the first change is done, you are updating the Counter property again => UI thread is blocked again.

So this is exactly what is expected.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.. Main problem is that i don see every value of counter in text box. I just see 0 before i click, then i click on the button, `UI` freezes and after few moments i see last loop value. Thread should be frozen during process, i get that, but why `UI` don't process every Notify from view model? I also made sure that `PropertyChanged` event is raised after every increment..

Comment: The UI does process every update. However, it never gets around to showing the new value to you visually, since you immediately update the value again. Rendering the UI has a lower priority than responding to the change of the property.

Comment: That right, i solved problem. That kind of work has to be done on another thread which will periodically send notifications to `UI Thread` and tell it to update UI. `BackgroundWorker` is pretty handy for that kind of work. :D